# cannot ping through gre tunnel

Tags: nat, ping, route, tunneling, gre

> ### This question has been merged

I have 4 machines

machine 1 have ip address 172.13.0.40/24
machine 2 have two ip address 172.13.0.1/24 and 172.12.0.1/24
machine 3 have two ip address 172.12.0.50/24 and 172.17.0.1/24
machine 4 have ip address 172.17.0.30/24

machine 2 and 3 have NAT on both ways

we can ping from machine machine 1 to machine 4 and vice versa

I need a tunnel 10.0.0.0/25 to be formed between machine 1 and 4

I used following commands

```
ip tunnel add gtt0001 mode gre remote 172.13.0.40 local 172.17.0.30 ttl 255 dev eth1

ip link set gtt0001 up

ip addr add 10.0.0.0/24 broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev gtt0001

ip link set gtt0001 multicast on

ifconfig gtt0001 10.0.0.21 netmask 255.255.255.0 

ip route add 172.13.0.0/24 dev gtt0001
```

similar commands on machine 4

But I cannot ping 10.0.0.21 from machine 4 and vice versa

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to ping through gre tunnel](http://serverfault.com/questions/290956/unable-to-ping-through-gre-tunnel)